# Ошибка при прорисовке кривой линий в в объекте Chart(WinForms)

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Не получается без ошибок отобразить несколько кривых в объекте Chart.То есть после добавления 2 кривой добавляется лишняя прямая линия которой мне не надо. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
double get_uniform()
{
        int number = rand();
        double result = (double)number / (RAND_MAX + 1);
        return(result);
}

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    vector<float>freq;

    float n = 0;//переменная для сохранения случ.значения.
    float d = 0;//Для сохранения частоты.
    int orel = 0;//Количество выпадений орла.
    int k = 0;
    int count = 0;
    count = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
    int count_1 = Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (int m = 0; m < count_1; m++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                n = get_uniform();
                if (n < 0.5) {
                    orel++;
                }
                k++;
                d = (double)orel / (double)k;
                if (d != 0 || d != 0.5 || d != 1) {
                    freq.push_back(d);
                }

            }

            for (int i = 1; i < freq.size(); i++) {
                chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(i, freq[i]);
            }
            freq.clear();
        }

        
        chart1->ChartAreas[0]->AxisX->IsLogarithmic = true;
    

    
}
```

Comment: очень тривиальный ответ,я ожидал более не очевидного.

Comment: Добавил к описанию вопроса

Comment: Как вы решили данную проблему?

Comment: Я использовал двумерный массив для каждой вновь созданной серии. Это объясняется тем, что на каждую серию производится сколько-то опытов значит мне нужен двумерный массив.